# Executing VBS file stored on a network drive through UFT

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

A VBScript file stored on shared network is to be utilized by UFT (which is installed on CITRIX)

In the below screenshot, Excel file at the same network location can be accessed but I'm unable to open VBScript file. [Line 1 to 12]

The file is "Test1.vbs" shown at line 6 in code below

Line 14, 15, 16 in the code below shows the generic ways to try and invoke it. but didn't work

```
        Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'excel application
        
        appExcel.Application.Visible = True
        
        '**********************
        strArea = "\\Files\rpl_pt_at\test1.vbs"
        strChain = "PT_Smoke"
        '**********************
        
        Set objWorkbook = appExcel.workbooks.open("\\Files\rpl_pt_at\"+ strChain + ".xlsx")

        appExcel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 'Activating the sheet"Scripts"
        
        executefile strArea
        invokeApplication "\\Files\rpl_pt_at\test1.vbs"
        SystemUtil.Run "\\Files\rpl_pt_at\test1.vbs", " "
```

**Note:: VBS and Excel File are at the same location on network**

**Note:: UFT is installed on a Citrix and not on the same network as the file.**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for you to map network to a drive letter eg. `Z:\`

That way you would be able to reference the folder with vbs file by declaring your vbs folder location as:

```
vbsfolder = "Z:\Files\rpl_pt_at"
```

Now you can use the file folder location and append the vbs file name as:

```
vbsfilelocwithname = vbsfolder & "\\" & "test1.vbs"
```

Then using how to run vbs script described here: https://www.learnqtp.com/forums/Thread-How-to-execute-the-two-vb-scripts-Consecutively

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
oShell.run vbsfilelocwithname, , True
```